# What would happen if master and slave can't communicate?

Tags: architecture, apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing

I am learning master-slave model in zookeeper. I just have a question:

What would happen if one master and one slave can't communicate to each other? like master can't get ACK from slave ? Would slave reboot itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends one how the quorum gets partitioned. You may know that zookeeper operates as a quorum of zookeeper servers. If two servers cannot talk to each other, that means there is a network partitioning problem (one set of servers cannot reach the other servers in different parts of a network). Since we use odd number of servers in the quorum, there will be two partitions, one with majority of servers and one with a minority.

**If leader is in the majority partition**,

quorum will continue to operate as the leader has the majority of the quorum. In the minority partition, servers will shutdown and go to a leader election phase. Following text is quoted from a mail thread in `user mail list` of Apache Zookeeper.

> After the partition, all the servers in the minority region will get shutdown and moves to leader election phase. All the client sessions
>   connected to these servers will be disconnected and will receive
>   "KeeperState.Disconnected" event to their watchers, if any registered.
>
> But ZooKeeper supports read-only server mode. In this mode, client can
>   connect to the read-only server even when the server might be
>   partitioned from the quorum.

**If the leader is in the minority partition,**

Again, a leader election will happen in both partitions and minority partition won't be able to elect a leader. Therefore, will shutdown. Majority partition will elect a new leader and continue operation.

In your question, what you refer as `master cannot connect to slave` is an example to network partitioning. Either the master (leader) is in the minority partition or the slave is in the minority partition.

Hope you got the idea :-)